# Delay in changing background color using Jquery in iPhone

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which changes the background color of a link when clicked.

```
function showSelectEffect(obj) {
        $(obj).css("background-color", "#d7d7d7");
            }
```

The method is called onclick of the link as below

```
<a onclick="showSelectEffect(this);" href="test.html">sample text</a>
```

The problem is that the highlight happens after a seconds delay and doesn't happen immediately when clicked. I've tried calling the showSelectEffect function on the onmousedown event but its still the same. Kindly let me know on how I can improve the performance.

Comment: I had similar problems with jQuery mobile, where it was taking a second or so to register any click event. Never got to the root of the problem, despite much Googling. I'm very interested to see if you get a good answer, assuming it's the same issue

Answer (score 2):

```
<a class="showSelectEffect" href="test.html">sample text1</a>
<a class="showSelectEffect" href="test.html">sample text2</a>
<a class="showSelectEffect" href="test.html">sample text3</a>
<a class="showSelectEffect" href="test.html">sample text4</a>​


$('.showSelectEffect').on('click',function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).css("background-color", "#d7d7d7");
});​
```

[***Try the demo here***](http://jsfiddle.net/VKLXM/)

You can try css rather than using jquery which will be little bit faster.

```
a:active {
   background-color:#d7d7d7; //this line should go in your stylesheet
}
```

Try to keep the JS code and the HTML separate. That's a good practise.

another option is to define the css class in the stylesheet like below.

```
a.showSelectEffectColor {
   background-color:#d7d7d7; //this line should go in your stylesheet
}

 $('.showSelectEffect').on('click',function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).addClass('showSelectEffectColor');
    });​
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `:active` css property?

```
/* CSS */
a:active {
   background-color:#d7d7d7;
}

/* HTML */
<a href="test.html">test</a>
```

Comment: Which browser and what device did you used? Maybe this is a capability problem of the device you used

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `addClass` function

```
.changeBackground{
   background-color:#d7d7d7;
}



$(body).addClass('changeBackground');
```